# Input Signal Frequency Estimation during Simulation Time in Simulink

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, fft, simulink

I need a Matlab function that can estimate the frequency of an input signal in Simulink during simulation time i.e. no postprocessing in Matlab.  I wrote the following code:

```
function frq_est = fcn(u)

persistent x_buff

num_data = 2000;

if isempty(x_buff),x_buff=zeros(num_data,1);end

x_buff(2:num_data) = x_buff(1:num_data-1);
x_buff(1)          = u;

Nfft    = 1024;
[Pxx,f] = pwelch(x_buff, gausswin(Nfft), Nfft/2, Nfft,1000);

[~,loc] = max(Pxx);

frq_est = f(loc);
```

[image]

This model sort of works, though with some error, in Matlab R2023a, but the same exact model won't in R2020a at all.  I need it to work in R2020a unfortunately.  The error I get from R202a is as follows:

```
Data 'frq_est' is inferred as a variable size matrix, while its properties in the Model Explorer specify its size as inherited or fixed. Please check the 'Variable Size' check box and specify the upper bounds in the size field.
Component:MATLAB Function | Category:Coder error
Simulink cannot determine sizes and/or types of the outputs for block 'frq_est_rt/MATLAB Function' due to errors in the block body, or limitations of the underlying analysis. The errors might be inaccurate. Fix the indicated errors, or explicitly specify sizes and/or types for all block outputs.
```

In addition, it seems that there is a constant offset.  As written, if the input signal is a 20Hz sine wave, it estimates that to be 19.5Hz.  If 10, 9.5.  Etc.

The questions are in the order of significance, 1 being the most important:

1. Is there a better way to do this?  Better as in more popular, proven
   working, widely used in the industries, etc.
2. How do I make this work
   in R2020a?
3. Why is there this offset in the output?